# SMS Retriever API - phone picker source

Tags: google-play-services

Does Google's SMS Retriever API get the list of phone numbers from the SIM lines on the user's device (which means that it's similar to TelephonyManager), or from the user's Google Play account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Please look at @Steven Soneff's answer

---

The numbers are retrieved from Smart Lock for Passwords on Android. They are retrieved if the user already stored it using Smart Lock else they will be empty. You may also ask the user to store the number for future use-cases using Smart Lock for Passwords.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the product manager at Google for this API. Yes, as of the latest version of Play Services, the Phone Selector shows both the phone number for the device from the TelephonyManager (if it can be parsed as as a valid phone number) as well as recent phone numbers for the active Google Accounts on the device.

Comment: I am sorry, without the documentation, that's what I understood. Also is TelephonyManager API available for all countries? Like I never got any number suggestion when I tried the same on my phone. :/

Comment: TelephonyManager is not reliable across all countries and OEMs ... unfortunately we do no yet surface phone numbers that have been saved with Smart Lock, only those recently verified for the Google Account settings.

Comment: @StevenSoneff I'm using SmsProviderApi + AutoCompleteTextView (set to input type `phone`. The Phone Selector UI shows only my google voice number, but the AutoCompleteTextView shows my real number.

How do I get the Phone Selector UI to show the correct number?

Comment: I need to filter sms auto-read based on who the sender is. Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly addressed from the docs but if we infer from this statement in the  [Obtain the user's phone number](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request):

> Often, it is the best user experience to use the hint picker to prompt
>   the user to choose from the phone numbers stored on the device and
>   thereby avoid having to manually type a phone number

we can deduce that SMS Retriever API gets the contacts from your device.